# "Позвонив Марии" или "позвонив Марие"?

Tags: орфография

"Позвонив Марии" или "позвонив Марие"?

Answer (score 4):

И "тянет" за собой И. Родительный, дательный, предложный падежи - форма с И - МариИ. НО МарьЕ, потому что после Ь.

Answer (score 0):

Мария - слово на -ия, поэтому родительный, дательный, предложный - и. Так же пишутся слова на -ий, -ие. Марии, но Марье: Марья - 1 склонение, пишется е.

Answer (score 0):

Дательный падеж - Позвонить кому? -МариИ

Answer (score 0):

Кому? Дательный падеж на -ИЯ, поэтому пишем -ИИ